# The Nature of Spring

Tags: dependency-injection, java-ee, spring

Is it accurate to say that dependency injection manually using java (without spring) is nothing but implementing the strategy pattern (as per this [example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#Code_illustration_using_Java))?

Furthermore, is it correct to say that Spring just provides a declarative way of specifying the dependency as opposed to manual method whereby the dependency need to be created and 'set' using java code?

Comment: @DocBrown: That doesn't appear to be a duplicate, although the OP can probably find his answer there.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: IMHO the other question may not be exactly a duplicate, but it covers the same ground and the answers there will provide also good answers here.

Comment: @DocBrown: Pretty much has to be exact to be a duplicate.  The questions, not the answers.  Just sayin'.

Comment: @RobertHarvey _'No argument about how exact an "exact duplicate" needs to be.'_ Just [quotin'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) guidelines on duplicates

Comment: @DocBrown your observation looks accurate, particularly regarding answers - I think that top two and especially [top third](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/92438/31260) make a great match to the question asked. Which is not surprising, given the role of DI in Spring

Comment: @gnat: Well, that's fine, I guess.  You guys apparently didn't read the first paragraph of the question, which the duplicate does not address at all.

Comment: @DocBrown: The duplicate makes no mention of the strategy pattern.

Comment: @RobertHarvey if you delete the second paragraph, I'll be the first to vote reopen (or flag to re-close). [Easy peasy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not/194495#194495)

Comment: @gnat: I think the problem is the title.  I've edited it, and voted to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency injection (whether done through the constructor or with a DI framework) is one way to implement the strategy pattern, but so is a factory method.

In general, DI frameworks (like the one implemented by Spring) allow you to declare system-wide injection dependencies in a single location.